# H2 and PostgreSQL compatibility mode limitations

Tags: postgresql, h2

I'm using H2 database as in-memory database for tests where PostgreSQL is being used in production. This setup works fine except some minor differences between the two. One I'm concerned about right now is the [64 length limit for identifiers in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html). [H2 seems to support sort of unlimited identifiers length](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations) which is causing troubles for me because I have dynamically generated schemas and once the column/table/schema identifiers are longer than 64 characters it works in H2 but the problem is revealed only after using PostgreSQL in some real environment.

I found the [PostgreSQL compatibility mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) for H2 but it doesn't seem to address this particular thing.

So the question:

Any idea how I can force H2 to treat identifiers in the same way as PosgreSQL does? I.e. if identifier is longer than 64 characters it will be truncated to 64 characters only.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need a second layer of tests, on a local Postgres instance (or just to drop the H2 step altogether). Otherwise, you're going to constantly run into problems like this, and you'll never be able to trust your tests, because nobody is going to be able to give you a 100% guarantee of like-for-like behaviour.

Comment: I agree, sure thing. There is pre-production environment testing against real (postgres) DB but I would still love to keep the in memory DB for pull-request builds which are quick and setting up Postgres on the CI build node seems to be overkill. Maintaining such thing with many concurrent builds adds complexity which I would love to avoid as long as possible.

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps there are other "out of the box" answers though - what about an assertion as part of the CI build that the database doesn't contain any identifiers longer than 64 characters? Would be pretty easy if H2 has `information_schema` support. If you just mimic the truncation, there's the temptation for your code to assume that behaviour, rather than limiting the generated names to a portable length.